# Clean solution for using APIs within Laravel?

Tags: php, json, api, laravel

Does anybody have a nice clean & most code efficient solution for using APIs within Laravel?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I just read this book https://leanpub.com/build-apis-you-wont-hate.  It's a very good resource on how to build API's and most of the examples use Laravel.

Comment: Sorry, you may have mis read the question. I already know how to build an API using Laravel. I am looking for the best and cleanest way to use an external API in Laravel.

Comment: Oh sorry, after reading it again, I realize I interpreted that exactly the opposite of what it really says.

Comment: No problem! Ordered the book anyway. Looks like an interesting read.

Comment: Are you familiar with repositories?

Comment: I have used the repository pattern in Laravel, yes.

Comment: Guzzle Service Descriptors - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing a lot of folks seem to forget is what the model really is in MVC.  Most of the time, they are just an abstraction layer for your database, but they don't have to be.  They can also be a service for interacting with an external API.

So with that said, when I am building out a feature on a site which uses an external API, I usually start with creating a model for the API.  I then try to name the methods as similar as possible to `Eloquent` methods just because that is what I am most used to working with and tends to make the most sense.

These methods simply interact with the API and you can even use the results from an API to fill out a collection object as well.  The idea is to design your model in a way where you don't even feel like you are interacting with a third-party API.

On top of the model, I would also build a repository which would contain any business logic your app requires to interact with the API.  For example, if you'd need to grab a certain item from the API, you might want to check your own database first for a cached version.  If there is none, grab the item from the API and cache/recache and then return the results to your controller.

Then you'd inject the repository into your controller and do whatever you need with it.

Also, it might be pretty obvious, but things like the API key and entry point into the API would go well in your config files or .env file depending on which Laravel version you are using.  Also would be best to use service providers to manage the dependency injection in the case you ever need to update your model in the event the third party comes out with a newer API version you want to use.  Coding your model to an interface in this case has potential to save you some headaches later.

And one last note, before you start, check packagist first.  There's no point in reinventing the wheel.